# Rebooting a device programmatically

Tags: android

I am building a background service for my consumption only. I need to reboot my device based on certain conditions.

1. I understand that for application/service to reboot a device, it needs to be a Systems Application.
2. Since, I ONLY would be using this application, is there a way to sign it for my device and use it for its said purpose ( reboot based on conditions )
3. If yes, can you please point me how to sign an application, so that It can become a System App, and if the .apk can be installed normally, as other apks
4. Any code reference for reboot will also help me to start the project, provided condition 2 satisfies

I am using  MI device, with Android 6.0. I would like to achieve this without rooting my device.

Adding the Code

```
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.REBOOT)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        System.out.println("Permission Ask");

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.REBOOT)) {
            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Explain",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.REBOOT},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_REBOOT);
        }

    } else {
        // Permission has already been granted
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You have been granter permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

       if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_REBOOT) {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Not Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request.
        }
```

Comment: You can't install your app as a system app without rooting the device. If you are fine with rooting the device then i can explain further.

Comment: @sak will this requirement require rooting, I mean Point 2

Answer (score 3):

If you want the device to reboot (power off and on), then try PowerManager.reboot()

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
powerManager.reboot(null);
```

[android.os.PowerManager:](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/PowerManager.java)

```
  /**
 * Reboot the device.  Will not return if the reboot is successful.
 * <p>
 * Requires the {@link android.Manifest.permission#REBOOT} permission.
 * </p>
 *
 * @param reason code to pass to the kernel (e.g., "recovery") to
 *               request special boot modes, or null.
 */
public void reboot(String reason) {
    try {
        mService.reboot(false, reason, true);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
    }
}
```

If you want to completely shutdown the device then use `PowerManagerService.shutdown()`

```
  IPowerManager powerManager = IPowerManager.Stub.asInterface(
        ServiceManager.getService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
try {
    powerManager.shutdown(false, false);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
}




   /**
 * Shuts down the device.
 *
 * @param confirm If true, shows a shutdown confirmation dialog.
 * @param wait If true, this call waits for the shutdown to complete and does not return.
 */
@Override // Binder call
public void shutdown(boolean confirm, boolean wait) {
    mContext.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.REBOOT, null);

    final long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    try {
        shutdownOrRebootInternal(true, confirm, null, wait);
    } finally {
        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(ident);
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting the error - when I execute the .reboot(null) code on click of a button. Not sure what is mistake Process: com.miui.miui.miuiservice, PID: 4579
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)

Comment: Ok, it shows me the this error - Neither user 10055 nor current process has android.permission.REBOOT. I have added the same in Manifest and added the Request permission code, but it still fails. [ Permission Not Done Message comes up ] Added the code in the main question

Comment: I believe permission.REBOOT and permission.SHUTDOWN require your application to be a system app. That is, installed by the manufacturer and in the initial system firmware. In android 9 I had to get my app installed in company tablets, and had to add those permissions in a whitelist, which is basically the manifest installed into a system folder separately... at any rate, you need your app to be a system app (or privileged), or be a superuser to obtain those permissions. This is so normal apps cant render user devices useless.